# GNU Octave wvtool

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to use wvtool but I think it doesn't exist for Octave. I get

```
warning: the 'wvtool' function belongs to the signal package from Octave Forge
but has not yet been implemented.
```

Is there any way to use it or there is another similar tool?

Comment: Short answer is no, it doesn't exist, nor anything similar, are you looking for a different answer?

Comment: wvtool seems to be a graphical interface to more basic windowing functions etc: you can find most of these basic functions in the [signal package from octave forge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/). If what you need is a GUI tool specifically, you could try using an external one (e.g. one from [this list](https://www.minidsp.com/applications/advanced-tools/fir-filter-tools) ) and see if you can export data from there and import it into octave for further analysis. Having said that, it's probably worth learning how to do it from the original functions since you can make automated scripts.